# NetSuite - CSV Import

Tags: csv, netsuite, import-csv

I have this search in NetSuite:

[image]

Through it down the csv file to update the estimated cost of the invoices. However, it is giving this import error:

> Invalid entity reference key "2966894" for subsidiary 1

[image], because in the NetSuite wizard I am not able to map the subsidiary field

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure that when you're mapping via internal ID/etc you're actually mapping to the internal ID? You can check by clicking the little pencil and ensuring it's mapping to "Internal ID" and not "Names"

Comment: Yes. What happens is that I can not find the subsidiary field to map. Other fields are correctly mapped.

Comment: The mapping screen for CSV imports only shows the fields that are available on the selected form during import.  On the "Import Options" screen of the import wizard, you can click to expand Advanced Options and there you can select a different form to use during the import process.  If the field is not available on the form, then it will not be available during the mapping process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved. What happens is that in the spreadsheet the Est Extended Cost field had to be as "Custom". In this case it would take 2 updates: one to zero costs and another to update according to the Average Cost. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pick apart your error.

At quick glance.
Invalid entity reference key "2966894" for subsidiary 1

You can check SuiteAnswer ID 35887.

1)
In there I would check first, if subsidiary "1" is active.
if entity "2966894" is active.

2) Then I would check, if entity "2966894" has subsidiary of "1"

3) Do you have multi-subsidiary customer enabled? I would still change the field on the body of entity "2966894" to the "Brasil" subsidiary first. And then run the test.

Hope this helps pal!

Answer (score 0):

You're mapping "2966894" to cliente, which I assume is the entity/customer id.

Click the little pencil next to cliente and switch it to "Internal ID". It shouldn't be "Names". I would also ensure that the ID you're mapping to is a current and active record.

Comment: The client is mapped correctly. What I need is to map the subsidiary field, which I'm not finding. How to map?